# Becoming immune against the common cold

Tags: common-cold

I've heard that there around 300 types of common cold.

Would it be possible to get infected by all of them and then achieve immunity for all of them, after having had the mother of all common colds?

Comment: I don't think you become immune to common cold after being infected with it. If you saw somewhere that we could, better link to it. (Otherwise it looks like the question is based on wrong info.)

Comment: I'm not stating that is is possible, I am asking if it is. I understand now that is is not possible.